# How to set a value according to another one selected in django admin

Tags: python, django

I need to save in `Artigo` table a sequence value according to the `Lei` associated, like in this picture:

[image]

If `lei_id` is 1, so for each `Artigo` added it must be add in sequence from 0 in `id_artigo_lei` field. If `lei_id` is 2, so for each `Artigo` added it must be add in sequence from 0 in `id_artigo_lei` and so forth..

Those data are inserted in django admin.
That's my model:

```
class Lei(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=100)

class Artigo(models.Model):
    artigo = models.TextField('Artigo')
    id_artigo_lei = models.IntegerField('Artigo Lei', blank=True, null=True)

    lei = models.ForeignKey(Lei, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Lei', related_name='artigos')
```

ps: I deleted some columns from `Artigo` table just to simplify..